# How does bayesian optimization with gaussian processes work?

Tags: optimization, bayesian, gaussian-process, bayesian-nonparametric

Could someone explain in simple words

1. what are gaussian processes
2. how does bayesian optimization work
3. and their combination?

Answer (score 1):

Gaussian processes are a way of interpolating between data using a kernel fit, but with a covariance matrix. Think of it as kernel regression, but with confidence intervals that can be drawn at every point.

This diagram from [this medium article](https://medium.com/uncountable-engineering/why-bayesian-optimization-picks-candidates-that-arent-predicted-to-perform-well-cf6bffa127a1) is explains how a combination of a Gaussian process and an acquisition function works in Bayesian optimization:
[image: Flowchart diagram of Bayesian optimization]

An optimization problem is one that has an objective, for example, you might want to find a global minimum. Given the predictions and the confidence interval of a Gaussian process, Bayesian optimization uses an acquisition function to choose observations that would advance that objective. The acquisition function is a combination of that objective, and a balance between exploration and exploitation.

The key concepts you should grasp are:

1. Bayesian optimization balances between exploring new and
   uninformed areas without data, and exploiting known information from
   pre-existing data.
2. This continually improves a Gaussian process
   model, so that it makes better decisions about what to observe next.
3. All of this is to optimize for a particular objective